# Loop through array to get all items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-item, item

I use sharepoint online and this is going to be an app

I need to loop through an array to get all items that are selected in a list, now i can only get one item but i need to get more items at once to do that i have .split(',') on this row:

```
itemId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListItemId")).split(',');
```

and i need an loop to go through all items that are selected

```
var i, array;
for (i = 0; i > array.length; i++)
    {


    }
```

and this is all code:

```
'use strict';

var clientContext, hostweburl, parentContext, parentWeb, selectedItem, itemId, listId;

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
listId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListId"));
itemId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListItemId")).split(',');
parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
parentWeb = parentContext.get_web();
selectedItem = parentWeb.get_lists().getById(listId).getItemById(itemId);


$(document).ready(function () {
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFail);
});



function OnSuccess() {

var i, array;
for (i = 0; i > array.length; i++)
    {


    }




$("#Blue").click(function () {

    selectedItem.set_item('Color', 'Blue');
    selectedItem.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
});

$("#Green").click(function () {

    selectedItem.set_item('Color', 'Green');
    selectedItem.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
});

$("#Red").click(function () {

    selectedItem.set_item('Color', 'Red');
    selectedItem.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
});

$("#Transparent").click(function () {

    selectedItem.set_item('Color', 'No Color');
    selectedItem.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
});

}


function OnFail() {
alert("Error");
}


function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
var params =
document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
var strParams = "";
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
        return singleParam[1];
}
}
```

**NOTE** i can't use SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);
because i will not have my code on the host web just on the app web and then this will not work

Answer (score 1):

i think what your looking for is:

```
var selectedItms = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);
```

> Gets the list items being selected.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409526(v=office.14).aspx

so it would look like this(change your for code for this one including changeing the selectedItems for this):

```
  var selectedItms = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);
  var itm;

  //loop though all selected items
  foreach (itm in selectedItms) 
  {
     //print to screen the current selected item
     alert(selectedItms[itm].id);
  }
```

Comment: can't use that need to loop trought all items

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
listId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListId"));
itemIds = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListItemId")).split(',');

var i;
for (i = 0; i < itemIds.length; i++)
{
    selectedItems = parentWeb.get_lists().getById(listId).getItemById(itemIds[i]);
    selectedItems.set_item('Color', color);
    selectedItems.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItems);
}
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
```